# How to choose between so many open-source bitcoin pool software

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, mining-pools, p2pool

I am now in the venture of finding and setting up a bitcoin pool company. However, after some research, I found out that there are plenty of bitcoin pool software. There are:

1. [CoiniumServ](https://github.com/bonesoul/CoiniumServ)
2. [Cryptonote Universal Pool](https://github.com/fancoder/cryptonote-universal-pool)
3. [MPOS](https://github.com/MPOS/php-mpos)
4. [NOMP](https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal)
5. [Bitcoin Pool](https://github.com/doublec/bitcoin-pool)

   etc.

I am actually quite confused about the differences of all these mining pool software. Can any kind soul help to explain the differences?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare and contrast the differences yourself. If you are going to become a pool operator, you will need to have a good enough understanding of Bitcoin, networking, and pool operation to do that. There is no correct answer, it all depends on your pool's business model and which features you find most important. This question is too vague to have a specific answer.